# Justify columns in tab delimited file using Advanced CSV

Tags: csv, sublimetext3

I have a tab delimited file open in Sublime Text 3 and would like to justify the columns. I have Advanced CSV installed and can specify the delimiter value, but neither a physical tab, nor a "\t" seem to be providing me the output I desire, which is to say that I'm not able to justify the columns correctly after setting this delimiter.

How can I justify a tab delimited file using Advanced CSV in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases you can actually just use a tab to set the file's delimiter character to a tab. As that is a sort of confusing sentence, here's an expansion on how to set your file's delimiter to a tab.

1. Open your Sublime options with `Cmd+Shift+P`
2. Find the "CSV: Set delimiter" option and select it
3. At the bottom of your Sublime program you will find the area where it would like you to your delimiting character
4. Hit the *tab* button on your keyboard
5. Hit enter to approve this new delimiting character

Comment: I don't see CSV: Set delimiter in the list of options on Sublime 3 :/

Comment: You have to install Advanced CSV. 
https://github.com/wadetb/Sublime-Text-Advanced-CSV